# entity framework: migration shows up empty

Tags: entity-framework

i am trying to migrate my db to the newest version.
i added this controller:

```
namespace TodoAppService.NET6.Controllers
{
    [Route("tables/gutcontroller")]
    public class GutController : TableController<GutItem>
    {
        public GutController(AppDbContext context)
            : base(new EntityTableRepository<GutItem>(context))
        {
        }
    }
}
```

this item:

```
public class GutItem : EntityTableData
{
    [Required, MinLength(1)]
    public string WasGeht { get; set; } = "";

    public bool IsHomo { get; set; }
}
```

this is my db context file:

```
   public partial class AppDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public AppDbContext() 
        {
        }
    
        protected override void On

Configuring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
        {
            IConfigurationRoot configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
               .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
               .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
               .Build();
            var connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
        }

    }

    public virtual DbSet<TodoItem> TodoItems { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<GutItem> GutItem { get; set; }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<TodoItem>(entity =>
        {
            entity.Property(e => e.Version)
                .IsRowVersion()
            .IsConcurrencyToken();
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<GutItem>(entity =>
        {
            entity.Property(e => e.Version)
                .IsRowVersion()
            .IsConcurrencyToken();
        });

        OnModelCreatingPartial(modelBuilder);
    }

    partial void OnModelCreatingPartial(ModelBuilder modelBuilder);
```

}´
and that is my program.cs:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Datasync;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");

if (connectionString == null)
{
    throw new ApplicationException("DefaultConnection is not set");
}

builder.Services.AddDbContext<DbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString, b => b.MigrationsAssembly("TodoAppService.NET6")));
builder.Services.AddDatasyncControllers();

var app = builder.Build();

// Initialize the database
using (var scope = app.Services.CreateScope())
{
    var context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<DbContext>();
    //await context.InitializeDatabaseAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
}

// Configure and run the web service.
app.MapControllers();
app.Run();
```

But always when I run the tools, the up and down methods come as empty.

Even if I manually put something in there (create table), nothing is happening on the backend.

Any tips?